# custom context.xml file for Tomcat 7 run from NetBeans 7

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, deployment, tomcat7, netbeans-7

I am trying to avoid putting passwords inside both the version-controlled files and the packaged files. In order to do this, I can't have a context.xml (which contains my DB information) inside my project.

I am currently deploying my war file with the Tomcat 7.0.35 Manager because it allows to specify the file path to the context.xml file on the server.

This all works fine except that I haven't found a way to do that in development from Netbeans 7.2.1. Therefore when I am trying to run my project in Netbeans, I get the following message

```
In-place deployment at (...)/trace
(...)/trace/target/trace/META-INF/context.xml (No such file or directory)
```

Any help for configuring Netbeans or for another way to fulfill my goal would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a suitable way to work that out for my specific situation. I have kept the `context.xml` but used the Apache [Ant-style variable substitution](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/index.html) which is supported by Tomcat.

There are [several ways to define the environment variables](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/index.html) but I chose to use the `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties` file, which seems more mainteanable to me. I also enclose a `catalina.example.properties` in my source files to document the variables expected by the application.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 5):

Netbeans requires a `META-INF/context.xml` for running your war from the IDE. From my observations if the `context.xml` doesn't exist it creates it.

How about keeping a `META-INF/context.xml` in your local project workspace, but add the path to your `.gitignore` (or SCM equivalent) so you don't accidentally commit it?

Comment: I thank you for your help, but the solution your offer would still force me to have a context.xml in my binaries, which would prevent them from being portable and secure.

Comment: @clark: This isn't an issue for me. Since context.xml is never committed, our build server (Jenkins) has no visibility of the file ever so  it's not included in the .war in a build